# Tight-binding extended attractive Hubbard model for unconventional superconductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, tight-binding

BCS theory suggest that the effective attraction between two electrons, due to electron-phonon coupling, is in momentum ($k-$)space. However, in literature, (real space) tight-binding Hubbard model with on-site repulsion and nearest neighbour attraction is generally accepted as an effective model for the description of the unconventional superconductors. This seems odd to me. Could anyone explain why is it okay to use the real space tight-binding Hamiltonian that seem to suggest that electrons 'attract' each other in real space. Isn't it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a Hubbard interaction hamiltonian (which I'll take to be onsite)
\begin{align}
H = U \sum_i c^{\dagger}_{i,\uparrow}c_{i,\uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{i,\downarrow}c_{i,\downarrow}.
\end{align}
We can Fourier transform the $c$, $c^{\dagger}$ operators
\begin{align}
c_{i,s} = \sum_k e^{i k x_i} c_{k,s},
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
H &= U \sum_i \sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4} e^{i (k_2 + k_4 - k_1 -k_3)x_i}c^{\dagger}_{k_1,\uparrow}c_{k_2,\uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{k_3,\downarrow}c_{k_4,\downarrow}\\
&=U\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4} \delta'_{k_2 + k_4 - k_1 -k_3}c^{\dagger}_{k_1,\uparrow}c_{k_2,\uparrow}c^{\dagger}_{k_3,\downarrow}c_{k_4,\downarrow}
\end{align}
where the $\delta'$ means total $k$ is conserved mod $2\pi$. In this way, we get a momentum space interaction (of whichever sign we want) from a real-space interaction.